# URL shortening with POST data

Tags: url-rewriting, http-post

Many services (eg, bit.ly) will shorten URLs, even those w/ GET data, 
since that's just part of the URL.

Do any work w/ POST data? In some cases (eg, certain types of CBOE 
option quotes), you must POST data to get the information you want.

The service might bring up a page (eg, shorten.com/foo) that has:

```
<form action="/url/to/post/to"> 
<input type="hidden" name="var1" value="val1"> 
... 
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"> 
</form>
```

where the /url/to/post/to and var1/val1/etc are set by the person 
creating the shortened URL. It would also say:

"By pressing the button below, you will post this data to this URL: 
/url/to/post/to: [list of hidden fields and values]"

Seems useful and easy to do... has anyone done it?

Comment: POSTing data can be used for spamming guestbooks etc. Any website like this is doomed to be used by spammers. Also, POSTing data is usually modification, while GETting data is usually request without modifiction. Transforming one into another is generally bad idea.

Comment: Many technologies can be used for evil, that doesn't make the technology itself evil. I disagree that POSTing data usually means changing something. Some sites simply choose to pass information using POST instead of GET (or cookies, or sessions, or whatever).

Comment: yes, some sites use post for retrieval.  That doesn't make it correct

Comment: You're saying sites should never use POST for data retrieval? It's wrong for http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/SimpleQuote.aspx to pass the stock symbol as POST data? I don't think I can agree with you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this seems to have degenerated into a moral argument. I'll assume the answer is no, no one has already done this.

Answer (score 0):

I see two big problems:

Who is going to copy / paste the form (often generated by javascript) - Regular users? It would only be open to people with enough technical competence to do it. And it may not do not have the intended effects since some data may be in cookies or held server-side.

Also, post requests are not usually considered an open api for anyone to use. Usually, data is built up over a series of steps with possible use of cookies and login information. Websites are not going to be happy with letting people delete their account or bypass certain pages that are in the normal process flow.

Comment: The idea here is that a sophisticated user (who knows how to use Firebug, sniff network traffic, etc) would create the page, and then send the URL to a less technical friend. In general, I'm interested in technologies where a techie user can make life easier for a regular user. Philosophically, I believe in using the web my way (eg, GreaseMonkey), so the second paragraph doesn't really dissuade me.